# Does Sodium carbonate and magnesium hydroxide react?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I understand Sodium carbonate and calcium hydroxide reacts, but I am surprised to see there is not any description regarding Sodium carbonate and magnesium hydroxide reaction. Is there a reason? do these two compounds react? Looking at solubility rule they should react and form precipitate.

[Double Displacement Reactions on libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Los_Angeles_Trade_Technical_College/Chem_51/1.7%3A_Types_of_Chemical_Reactions/7.01%3A_Types_of_Chemical_Reactions_-_Double_Displacement_Reactions)

Comment: magnesium hydroxide is practically insoluble in water (solubility is 0.0064 g/L at room temperature) compared to calcium hydroxide (solubility of 1.6g/L).

Comment: The key is taking solubility product of magnesium hydroxide and magnesium carbonate and evaluate the equilibrium.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, sodium carbonate is used as a water softener. It supposedly reacts with magnesium hydroxide to form 'magnesium carbonate' (https://www.tatachemicalseurope.com/applications/water-purification).
The 'magnesium carbonate' might actually be magnesium carbonate hydrates (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-02261-8).
Presumably, since sodium carbonate can raise the pH to values > 11, one might have to work with diluted solutions of sodium carbonate and magnesium hydroxide, such that the pH is not much lower than 9 (magnesium carbonate dissolution) and not much higher than 10 (magnesium hydroxide precipitation).